# Multiple groups in the same pattern separated by ORs but keep the group index constant

Tags: regex

(Apologies for the confusing title, not sure how to phrase it better)

Given this sample text:

> Save 10% on all items when ...

sometimes it can also be something like:

> Additionally 20% off just today

(the text will never have both sentences at the same time)

I want to capture either percentage value.
I have tried this pattern: `/(\d{1,2})% off|Save (\d{1,2})%/`

but then `10` is in group index **2** and `20` is in group index **1**

I want it to capture under the same group index, eg.:

```js
matches = text.match(/(\d{1,2})% off|Save (\d{1,2})%/)

// matches[1] == '10'
// or
// matches[1] == '20'
```

Comment: Use lookarounds, `/\d{1,2}(?=% off)|(?<=Save )\d{1,2}(?=%)/` and `matches[0]`

Comment: Why does it matter which group captured ? I mean result is always `$1$2` right ? Rediculous. string result = "$1$2"; I mean you can do gyrations of assertions but it's not necessary. Put down the qualifying text. There is only one match at a time, concantenate the groups. Like a sort, always put the pre-percentage qualifying verbage first, post (if needed) last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to match the following regular expression.

```
(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?=% off)|(?<=Save )\d{1,2}(?=%)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8X98X/1)

Without the negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` `"123456% off"` (for example) would be matched.

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<!        # begin negative lookbehind
  \d        # match a digit
)           # end  negative lookbehind
\d{1,2}     # match 1 or 2 digits
(?=         # begin positive lookahead
  % off     # match '% off'
)           # end positive lookahead
|           # or
(?<=        # begin positive lookbehind
  Save[ ]   # match 'Save '
)           # end positive lookbehind
\d{1,2}     # match 1 or 2 digits
(?=         # begin positive lookahead
  %         # match '%'
)           # end positive lookahead
```